# Get Intranet windows username in php

Tags: php, ldap

```
i can get the windows username in my system but i need to retrieve the windows username from **visitors**.
```

Visitor means not **internet** am saying about **intranet**.

Am developing intranet website for this only i need:

Below the code for your reference:-

```
/* to get the windows username */
$nw = new COM("WScript.Network");
print "username: " . $nw->username . "<br><br>";
$computername = $nw->computername;
print "computername: $computername<br>";
$owmi = new COM("winmgmts:\\\\$computername\\root\\cimv2");
$comp = $owmi->get("win32_computersystem.name='$computername'" );
print "username: " . $comp->username; echo "<br>";
/* to get the windows username */
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your php version use $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] or $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], one of those should work.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more info

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for basic authentication

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for NTLM authentication

Comment: The pages in question also have to be protected using some sort of authentication through IIS.  If you aren't on a windows domain than you'll need to use basic authentication.  If you are on a domain you can use NTLM to pass windows credentials to the site.

Comment: Just to be clear though, are you running your webserver on a linux machine and trying to connect windows clients to it or are you running apache on a windows machine as an alternative to using IIS? Regardless you're problem is that you need some sort of authentication on your site so that the webserver differentiates one client from another(I assume now that you just have anonymous authentication which will not differentiate one user from another)

Comment: right now am testing this in windows xp but after test finish i will move my projects to windows 2003 server. but my all users are using windows xp/7...

Comment: am not using linux.. i just using windows xp. i have windows 2003 server.. if this functionality is working only in windows server 2003 means i can shift the program to server...

Comment: I would recommend using IIS since you are using windows because it is much more user friendly than apache.  If you followed my link above there are a bunch of steps you need to go through to enable authentication with apache whereas with IIS you can do the same thing in almost no time with IIS manager.